# IOS Charts - Values on X-Axis not formatted correctly in portrait mode

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I'm in the process of integrating "IOS Charts" into my latest app. Everything is fine but formatting of XAxis isn't running properly in portrait mode on IOS (see Screenshot). Landscape mode is fine. Chartsdata contain 290 entries with date / numeric value. Some formatting is obviously done but not enough. (see screenshots)
[image: screenshot portrait]
[image: screenshot landscape]
I am working with Xcode 8 / Swift 3 / latest build from CocoaPods (version 3.0.0 of Charts) / IOS 10

Here is my only code relating to Xaxis, where "Charty" is my LineChartView

```
    Charty.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    Charty.xAxis.granularity = 10
    Charty.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    Charty.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true
```

Comment: A Workaround limits the number of visible Labels on Xaxis ` Charty.xAxis.setLabelCount(5, force: true)`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code while it is in portrait mode.

```
    lineChartView.xAxis.spaceBetweenLabels = 4
    lineChartView.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = false
```

spaceBetweenLabels will help you to align things on xAxis.

Comment: While it does sound promising... "spaceBetweenLabels" is obviously not a part of the Library any more. Could it be, that it has been replaced by "spaceMin" and "spaceMax" ?